# SQL SERVER xml with CDATA

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, cdata

I have a table in my database with a column containing xml. The column type is nvarchar(max). The xml is formed in this way

```
<root>
  <child>....</child>
  .
  .
  <special>
   <event><![CDATA[text->text]]></event>
   <event><![CDATA[text->text]]></event>
  ...
  </special>
</root>
```

I have not created the db, I cannot change the way information is stored in it but I can retrieve it with a select. For the extraction I use 
    select cast(replace(xml,'utf-8','utf-16')as xml)
    from table

It works well except for cdata, whose content in the query output is: text -> text

Is there a way to retrieve also the CDATA tags?

Comment: Hi, I am not having time to test the given solution, I'll update the question asap. If youhave alternative solution, I ma happy to test it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is - as far as I know - not possible on normal ways...

The **`CDATA` section has one sole reason**: include **invalid characters *within* XML for lazy people**...

`CDATA` is not seen as needed at all and therefore is not really supported by normal XML methods. Or in other words: It is supported in the way, that the content is properly escaped. There is no difference between correctly escaped content and not-escaped content within `CDATA` actually! (Okay, there are some minor differences like including `]]>` *within* a `CDATA`-section and some more tiny specialties...)

### The big question is: Why?

What are you trying to do with this afterwards?

Try this. the included text is given *as is*:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
'<root>
  <special>
   <event><![CDATA[text->text]]></event>
   <event><![CDATA[text->text]]></event>
  </special>
</root>'

SELECT t.c.query('text()')
FROM @xml.nodes('/root/special/event') t(c);
```

So: Please explain some more details: What do you really want?

If your really need nothing more than the wrapping `CDATA` you might use this:

```
SELECT '<![CDATA[' + t.c.value('.','varchar(max)') + ']]>'
FROM @xml.nodes('/root/special/event') t(c);
```

### Update: Same with outdated `FROM OPENXML`

I just tried how the outdated approach with `FROM OPENXML` handles this and found, that there is absolutely no indication in the resultset, that the given *text* was within a `CDATA` section originally. The "Some value here" is exactly returned in the same way as the text within `CDATA`:

```
DECLARE @doc XML = 
'<root>
  <child>Some value here </child>
  <special>
   <event><![CDATA[text->text]]></event>
   <event><![CDATA[text->text]]></event>
  </special>
</root>';

DECLARE @hnd INT;

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hnd OUTPUT, @doc;  

SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@hnd, '/root',0);

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hnd;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to include cdata on child nodes in XML, using pure SQL. But; it's not ideal.

```
SELECT 1 AS tag, 
   null AS parent, 
   '10001' AS 'Customer!1!Customer_ID!Element', 
   'AirBallon Captain' AS 'Customer!1!Title!cdata', 

   'Customer!1' = (
        SELECT 
               2 AS tag, 
               NULL AS parent, 
               'Wrapped in cdata, using explicit' AS 'Location!2!Title!cdata' 
               FOR XML EXPLICIT)

FOR XML EXPLICIT, ROOT('Customers')
```

CDATA is included, but Child element is encoded using

```
&gt;
```

instead of >
Which is so weird from a sensable point of view. I'm sure there are technical explanations, but they are stupid, because there is no difference in the *FOR XML* specification.

You could include the option `type` on the inner child node and then loose cdata too.. 
BUT WHY OH WHY?!?!?!?! would you (Microsoft) remove cdata, when I just added it?

```
<Customers>
  <Customer>
    <Customer_ID>10001</Customer_ID>
    <Title><![CDATA[AirBallon Captain]]></Title>
     &lt;Location&gt;
       &lt;Title&gt;&lt;![CDATA[wrapped in cdata, using explicit]]&gt;&lt;/Title&gt;
     &lt;/Location&gt;
 </Customer>
</Customers>
```