# how to extract database xml data in soapui

Tags: json, xml, groovy, soapui

My data is saved in SQL Server 2014 in xml format, and in SOAPUI JDBC request it is coming in this format

```
<Results>
<ResultSet fetchSize="128">
<Row rowNumber="1">
  <ConfigurationXML><![CDATA[<ROOT><Device>[{"Name":"AL","Profile":{"ID":1,"Height":240},"Index":-1}]</Device></ROOT>]]></ConfigurationXML> 
</Row>
</ResultSet>
</Results>
```

I want to compare this data with my REST Json Response, But how can I fetch data from this CDATA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample jdbc response provided by is little complex. Needs to be retried in multiple phases based on the nature of the data.

- Response xml has `CDATA`
- CDATA again has `Xml`
- That xml has `json`

Please find the below groovy script to retried final json and retrieving its properties as shown below.

Script is done with appropriate comments in line.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import groovy.json.*
//Sample response
def response = '''<Results>
<ResultSet fetchSize="128">
<Row rowNumber="1">
  <ConfigurationXML><![CDATA[<ROOT><Device>[{"Name":"AL","Profile":{"ID":1,"Height":240},"Index":-1}]</Device></ROOT>]]></ConfigurationXML> 
</Row>
</ResultSet>
</Results>'''
//Create the xml holder object for the jdbc response
def holder = new XmlHolder(response)
//Get ConfigurationXML Node value using Xpath from holder object, which will retrive CDATA
def configurationXmlCdata =  holder.getNodeValue('//*:ConfigurationXML')
log.info "Configruation Xml Cdata: ${configurationXmlCdata}"
//There is again xml inside CDATA, so create xml holder object to retried json string
def cdataHolder = new XmlHolder(configurationXmlCdata)
def jsonString = cdataHolder.getNodeValue('//ROOT/Device')
log.info "Device Json data: ${jsonString}"
//Create Json slurper object if you need to access json
def jsonData = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonString)
log.info jsonData.Name
log.info jsonData.Index
log.info jsonData.Profile.ID
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to convert XML to string then replace characters and finally cast the replaced character expression back to XML

```
declare @xml xml = '
<Results>
<ResultSet fetchSize="128">
<Row rowNumber="1">
  <CONFIGURATIONXML>&lt;ROOT&gt;&lt;/Device&gt;[{"Name":"AL","Profile":{"ID":1,"Height":240},"Index":-1}]&lt;/ROOT&gt;</CONFIGURATIONXML> 
</Row>
</ResultSet>
</Results>
'

select replace(replace( CAST(@xml as nvarchar(max)),'&lt;','<'),'&gt;','>')
    -- CAST( replace(replace( CAST(@xml as nvarchar(max)),'&lt;','<'),'&gt;','>') as xml)
```

But it fails because of the DEVICE tag
It should be in

Comment: This is not necessary... Reading from XML will replace escaped characters implicitly. You might see my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Reading the value properly will de-code the characters implicitly.

But: **Your inner XML is not valid!**:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<Results>
  <ResultSet fetchSize="128">
    <Row rowNumber="1">
      <CONFIGURATIONXML>&lt;ROOT&gt;&lt;/Device&gt;[{"Name":"AL","Profile":{"ID":1,"Height":240},"Index":-1}]&lt;/ROOT&gt;</CONFIGURATIONXML>
    </Row>
  </ResultSet>
</Results>';
SELECT @xml

SELECT @xml.value('(/Results/ResultSet/Row/CONFIGURATIONXML)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

Leads to:

```
<ROOT></Device>[{"Name":"AL","Profile":{"ID":1,"Height":240},"Index":-1}]</ROOT>
```

As you can see, the `</DEVICE>` is a closing tag, but there's no opening tag for this...

Don't know how this is created... If this is always the same, you could repair this like this:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(@xml.value('(/Results/ResultSet/Row/CONFIGURATIONXML)[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'</Device>','') AS XML).value('/ROOT[1]','varchar(max)')
```

The result

```
[{"Name":"AL","Profile":{"ID":1,"Height":240},"Index":-1}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but there is some misunderstanding , may be my question is not as clear , actually the data is coming in SOAPUI JDBC request, and I want to compare it with my json response values, and for this I have to write a groovy script but my question is how can I extract the data which is enclosed in CONFIGURATIONXML

Comment: @Geeta, Isn't this exactly what the first code-block does? My *Leads to* is the result fo the first `SELECT`, which is the content of the given element...

Comment: yes it works but it is not working on my actual data as I want, it combines CDATA string and remove all tags

Comment: Please avoid chameleon-questions: My answer really answered your question as it was given before. This is now a new issue, because reading (and **getting it out**) of a `CDATA`-section is a completely new issue. In short: This is not possible. The `CDATA` will get lost with XML approaches. But you might just add it like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38547537/5089204