# How to use CDATA in SQL XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, cdata

Could someone please help me with an XML output template please. I have been requested by a client to create an xml output file. This file will then feed in to Client's CRM. So that's why, it has to be an exact match of Client's requested template. I have managed to match it perfectly apart from CDATA for couple of fields.

below is the query you can use for testing purposes. I need CDATA wrap for fields Client and Area. I have also attached the output i am getting by running below code

```
            If OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') is Not NULL
            Drop table #Temp

            CREATE TABLE #Temp
            (
                [ShiftDate] [date] NULL,
                [Ref_Num] [varchar](20) NULL,
                [Agency_Worker_Name] [varchar](100) NULL,
                [Client] [varchar](100) NULL,
                [Area] [VarChar] (100) Null,
                [Assignment] [varchar](20) NULL,
                [Contract_Start] [varchar](30) NULL,
                [Contract_End] [varchar](30) NULL,
                [Contract_BreakInMinutes] [varchar](10) NULL,
                [Contract_Total] [varchar](30) NULL,
                [Actual_Start] [varchar](30) NULL,
                [Actual_End] [varchar](30) NULL,
                [Actual_BreakInMinutes] [varchar](10) NULL,
                [Actual_Total] [varchar](30) NULL,
                [Commission] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
                [Total_Cost] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
                [Rate] [varchar](20) NULL,
                [OverallCost] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
                [AgencybackingReport] [int] NULL,
                [AccountCode] [varchar](20) NULL
            )

            Insert Into #Temp
            Values 
            ('2018-07-24',
             '83076641',
             'ABCD',
             'ABCD',
             'ABCD',
             'CPA00',
             '09:00',
             '17:00',
             '30',
             '07:30',
             '10:30',
             '17:00',
             '30',
             '05:30',
             '28.49',
             '159.01',
             'Basic',
             '221.59',
             '1220883',
            ' ABCD')



            Declare @xml Int=(Select max(AgencyBackingReport)  From #Temp)

            select @xml As [@AgencyBackingReport],(Select 
            [Ref_Num] As [@reference],
            [ShiftDate] as [@startdate],
            Case When [AccountCode] is NULL Then 'Unknown' Else [AccountCode] End as [@accountcode],
            Contract_Start As 'PlannedShift/Start',
            Contract_End As 'PlannedShift/End',
            Contract_BreakInMinutes As 'PlannedShift/BreakinMinutes',
            Actual_Start As 'ActualShift/Start',
            Actual_End As 'ActualShift/End',
            Actual_BreakInMinutes As 'ActualShift/BreakinMinutes',
            OverallCost As [OverallCost],
            Agency_Worker_Name As 'AdditionalInformation/WorkerName',
            Client  As 'AdditionalInformation/Client',
            Area As 'AdditionalInformation/Area',
            -- ( select 
            --         1 as Tag ,
            --        0 as Parent ,
            --            (Select 
            --         Area 
            --        From #Temp M2
            --   Where M1.Ref_Num = m2.Ref_Num)
            --   As [Area!1!!CDATA]
            --   for xml explicit 
            --)   As 'AdditionalInformation/Area',
            Assignment As 'AdditionalInformation/Assignment',
            Commission As 'AdditionalInformation/Commission',
            Total_Cost As 'AdditionalInformation/TotalCost',
            Rate As 'AdditionalInformation/Rate'
            From #Temp M1
            for xml path('Shift'),Type)
            for XML Path('Shifts'),Type
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good question, +1 from my side...

Answer (score 5):

You seem to know that `CDATA` is rather outdated... If you want to read something about this you might follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39485752/5089204) and the links in this answer.

Sometimes we have to stick with it... Especially if poorly done third party tools demand for it. However...

The only way to include `CDATA` sections is to use `FOR XML EXPLICIT`, but this is rather clumsy.

### One problem you must be aware of: You cannot store this in XML type!

Whenever you convert an XML including a `CDATA` section from string type to native XML your CDATA will get lost and will be a properly escaped normal `text()` node.

Try this

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(XmlAsString NVARCHAR(MAX), NativeXml XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl 
SELECT (
        SELECT 1      AS Tag
              ,NULL   AS Parent
              ,'test <&>' AS [SomeNode!1!!cdata]
        FOR XML EXPLICIT
        )
       ,(
        SELECT 1      AS Tag
              ,NULL   AS Parent
              ,'test <&>' AS [SomeNode!1!!cdata]
        FOR XML EXPLICIT
        );

SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

The result

```
<SomeNode><![CDATA[test <&>]]></SomeNode>   
<SomeNode>test &lt;&amp;&gt;</SomeNode>
```

In short: Keeping CDATA sections forces you to remain in string type. Might be a big draw back...

### Back to your issue

If I see this correctly, you want to get everything like above, but

```
<Area><![CDATA[ABCD]]></Area>
```

... instead of

```
<Area>ABCD</Area>
```

### Approach 1 (ugly):

Create the XML as you do it above, then *read* the content of `<Area>` and use a `REPLACE` on string level to change this node entirly. But you must not convert this ever back to XML...

### Approach 2 (clumsy):

This is your XML with the `CDATA` section, not absolutely complete, but you see the principles:

```
SELECT   1          AS Tag
        ,NULL       AS Parent
        ,1220883    AS [Shifts!1!AgencyBackingReport]
        ,NULL       AS [Shift!2!reference]
        ,NULL       AS [Shift!2!startdate]
        ,NULL       AS [Shift!2!accountcode]
        ,NULL       AS [PlannedShift!3!Start!Element]
        ,NULL       AS [PlannedShift!3!End!Element]
        ,NULL       AS [PlannedShift!3!BreakingMinutes!Element]
        ,NULL       AS [ActualShift!4!dummy!Element] --just a dummy
        ,NULL       AS [OverallCost!5]
        ,NULL       AS [AdditionalInformation!6!WorkerName!Element]
        ,NULL       AS [AdditionalInformation!6!Area!CDATA]
        ,NULL       AS [AdditionalInformation!6!Assignment!Element]
UNION ALL
SELECT 2
      ,1
      ,NULL
      ,83076641
      ,'2018-07-24'
      ,'ABCD'
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 3
      ,2
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,'09:00'
      ,'17:00'
      ,30
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 --just a dummy
      ,2
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,'dummy'
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 5 
      ,2
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,211.59
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 6
      ,2
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,'ABCD'
      ,'ABCD'
      ,'CPA00'
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

The result

```
<Shifts AgencyBackingReport="1220883">
  <Shift reference="83076641" startdate="2018-07-24" accountcode="ABCD">
    <PlannedShift>
      <Start>09:00</Start>
      <End>17:00</End>
      <BreakingMinutes>30</BreakingMinutes>
    </PlannedShift>
    <ActualShift>
      <dummy>dummy</dummy>
    </ActualShift>
    <OverallCost>211.59</OverallCost>
    <AdditionalInformation>
      <WorkerName>ABCD</WorkerName>
      <Area><![CDATA[ABCD]]></Area>
      <Assignment>CPA00</Assignment>
    </AdditionalInformation>
  </Shift>
</Shifts>
```

Comment: Many thanks @shnugo for taking the time out of your busy routine and explaining it in a such a detail. Much much appreciated. I have just tried your solution, it works perfectly well for one Timesheet or row of data but when i apply this on my table/multiple rows, it doesn't give me what i need. I will try to attach the screenshot of my required output (only if Stackover flow website lets me do it) as i couldn't do it yesterday.

Comment: @user3482527 if you call the `SELECT` without the `FOR XML EXPLICIT` a table is returned. It might help to have a look at this, to understand how this works...

Comment: Many thanks mate, i will try this now. I have attached the required xml output in my question above now.

Comment: @user3482527: As you have to keep the result in `NVARCHAR(MAX)` it would be easiest to create all your shifts separately and use simple string concatenation to combine them and add the root node. Even more clumsy :-D

Answer (score 1):

Use the FOR XML in your query.

```
E.g: select * from table1 FOR XML AUTO
```

A statement like this (based on the infamous ):

```
SELECT 
   CustomerID as "@CustomerID",
   CompanyName,
   Address as "address/street",
   City as "address/city",
   Region as "address/region",
   PostalCode as "address/zip",
   Country as "address/country",
   ContactName as "contact/name",
   ContactTitle as "contact/title",
   Phone as "contact/phone", 
   Fax as "contact/fax"
FROM Customers
FOR XML PATH('Customer')
```